# How to position inlines in Django Admin in the list_display property?

Tags: django, django-admin

I have two tables related `Quiz` and `Difficulty_level`:

I have created `inline` in admin.py like this:

```
class DifficultyLevelInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = DifficultyLevel
```

and included in `QuizAdmin`

To arrange the list order, I would do:

```
  list_display = ('name', 'description', 'publication_date', 'category', 'is_active', 'is_premium')
```

How can I add `inlines` in the list_display order. I want to display The `DifficultyLevelInline` before `category`.

Comment: This is possible to do in 2019 with a function on the ModelAdmin class: `def related_name_you_want_before_category(self, obj): return obj.related_property` and adding the function name it in the list_display. for optimization of the admin SQL query you can load the related with select_related(related_name_you_want_before_category)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not possible using the default template.

If you take a look at change_form template:

https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/change_form.html

You can see that inlines are always rendered after fieldsets.

One way to get around this would be to use other template:

```
class MyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name', 'description', 'publication_date', 'category', 'is_active', 'is_premium')
    inlines = (DifficultyLevelInline,)
    change_form_template = "my_change_form.html"
```

Comment: Yes. I was almost sure that's not possible using default template. Thanks for the input.

Comment: This is possible to do in 2019 with a function on the ModelAdmin class: def related_name_you_want_before_category(self, obj): return obj.related_property and adding the function name it in the list_display. for optimization of the admin SQL query you can load the related with select_related(related_name_you_want_before_category)

Comment: your answer doesn't answer the OP question. He asked how to order in list_display, not when editing the records. But you will answer my question so I will give you thumbs UP

Answer (score 4):

Grapelli supports it: https://django-grappelli.readthedocs.org/en/latest/customization.html#rearrange-inlines

Basically, it uses a placeholder via fieldsets and then moves them HTML via JavaScript:
https://github.com/sehmaschine/django-grappelli/blob/master/grappelli/templates/admin/change_form.html#L90-96 (search for placeholder, if the lines do not match anymore).

The same can be done by injecting custom javascript yourself (with or without using fieldsets as placeholders).

Comment: I didn't understand what grapelli rearrange-inlines trying to explain. Where can i find the placeholder and id? Assuming I have 3 inlines `inlines             = (StatementsInline, PPPInline, RSLInline,)` What do I need to replace here in this example - `("Image Inlines", {"classes": ("placeholder images-group",), "fields" : ()}),` to insert my inlines, thx

Comment: @Charlesliam "placeholder" is used as-is (as a string). The id ("images-group") can be found by inspecting the HTML for example. It is probably derived from your model, e.g. "image" => "images-group". So with a model Foo, you would use: `("Image Inlines", {"classes": ("placeholder foos-group",), "fields" : ()}),`

Comment: @ShashankHegde hard to help without information.  But i am not using Grapelli anymore currently anyway.  Anyway: when asking questions, please provide some feedback.  I am typing now since 1m+ because of this, and could have done better.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution here: https://blog.devgenius.io/django-admin-dynamic-inline-positioning-7208596479ce

```
class MyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name', 'description', 'difficulty_level_inline', 'publication_date', 'category', 'is_active', 'is_premium')
    inlines = (DifficultyLevelInline,)

    def difficulty_level_inline(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = getattr(self.response, 'context_data', None) or {}
        inline = context['inline_admin_formset'] = context['inline_admin_formsets'].pop(0)
        return get_template(inline.opts.template).render(context, self.request)

    def render_change_form(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
      self.request = request
      self.response = super().render_change_form(request, *args, **kwargs)
      return self.response
```

Answer (score 0):

- Suppose here is your inline model:

```py
# models.py
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group


class MoreGroup(models.Model):
    group = models.OneToOneField(Group, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='more_group')
    explain = models.CharField(verbose_name="explain_info", max_length=64, blank=True, null=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(verbose_name="is_actived", default=True, blank=True, null=True)
```

- then do this:

```py
# admin.py
from . import models


class MoreGroupInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = models.MoreGroup
    can_delete = False
    verbose_name_plural = 'more_info'


class MyGroupAdmin(GroupAdmin):
    list_display = ['id', 'name', 'get_inline_info']
    def get_inline_info(self, obj) -> str:
        mg = models.MoreGroup.objects.filter(group=obj)
        if mg.count():
            return mg[0].explain
        else:
            return '-'
    get_inline_info.short_description = 'explain_info'

admin.site.register(models.Group, MyGroupAdmin)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found an app for exactly this:
https://github.com/robertkovac/django-fieldsets-with-inlines

```py
class MyModelAdmin(FieldsetsInlineMixin, admin.ModelAdmin):
    ...
    fieldsets_with_inlines = [
        (None, {
            'fields': [
                'name',
                'slug',
            ],
        }),
        RelatedThingInline,
        ('Moar Feelds', {
            'is_great',
            'is_neet',
        }),
    ]
```

Works for me on Django 4.1.